# Spring OAuth ClassCast from principal to user obj

Tags: java, xml, spring, oauth

We've recently ugpraded Spring Security from 3.1.3 to 4.01, and we've had to make some changes to our OAuth configs that left some requests breaking with a class cast when they try to cast the principal to a user -- specifically, it's the string form of the client id.

Here are the relevant sections of our configs.

For context, our standard auth management (which returns a user for the principal):

```
<!-- define an authentication-manager who uses a custom userDetailService -->
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Utility username / password form based authentication-provider -->
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminUserDetailsService">
         <!-- etc. -->
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

Secondly, our filter that looks stuff up in a oauth client details table and adds auth:

```
<bean id="oauth2ProviderFilter" class="blah.blah.blah.BlahOAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager">
            <property name="tokenServices" ref="oauth2TokenServices" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="oauth2TokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- etc... -->
</bean>
```

Checking the token in the headers:

```
<bean id="oauth2ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/oauth/authorize" />
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="oauthAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="oauthAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="oauthDaoAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="oauthDaoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="oauthUserDetailService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="oauthPasswordEncoder" />
</bean>
```

Our best theory at the moment is that something within the endpoint filter has stopped doing a look up of the user object and instead just returns the user id -- is this known to be the case? Where have we gone wrong in our set up?